# WinPhone7 pass values with special character between pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, parameters, navigation

I am going to pass string value between pages.
The value contains "&" character.
Since the values are split using "&", so the value is chopped.
How can I escape this special character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use URL encoding...
for ex: if you want '&' .. use '& amp;' (no spaces)

Recommended way is to use

```
Uri.EscapeUriString(stringToEscape)
```

method which does this for you.

Documentation at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=VS.95%29.aspx